# Is there way to close Guake tab by center click?

Tags: terminal, guake

I want to close Guake's tab by mouse wheel click.
As far as I see there is no configuration for it.

Is there a way to do it? For example by configuring with a `~/.guakerc` file or so.

Comment: Clicking the mouse wheel pastes the clipboard. Are you sure you want to give up this functionality?

Comment: ya, I want to close a tab that I click. But of course I want to also pastes the clipboard if the cursor is inside the console.